# Reverse Proxy to riderect some traffic to my Laravel application server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a reverse proxy to redirect some traffic to my laravel backend server.  My Laravele backend server is behind a VPN.    Below is my proxy nginx block

```
server {
    listen 80;


    server_name <proxy domain>;

    # Increase buffer sizes to handle large headers/cookies
    client_header_buffer_size 8k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;
    client_body_buffer_size 10M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass <Laravel IP>;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

The problem I keep having is that i keep going back and forth in increasing the nginx workings and increasing the headers as they are too large.   after going back and forth in increasing workings and headers size, my suspicion is that there is some configuration issue or some sort of loop as my Larvel backend is not that complicated lol.  Thoughts?